# How to convert std::chrono::zoned_time to std::string

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, c++-chrono, ostringstream

What is the most efficient way to convert from `std::chrono::zoned_time` to `std::string`?

I came up with this simple [solution](https://godbolt.org/z/GqfPxnKa5):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>


#if __cpp_lib_chrono >= 201907L
[[ nodiscard ]] inline auto
retrieve_current_local_time( )
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return zoned_time { current_zone( ), system_clock::now( ) };
}
#endif

int main( )
{
    const std::chrono::zoned_time time { retrieve_current_local_time( ) };
    const auto str { ( std::ostringstream { } << time ).str( ) };

    std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

As can be seen, `time` is inserted into the `ostringstream` object using the `operator<<` and then a `std::string` is constructed from its content.

Is there anything better than this in the standard library?

BTW, why doesn't the above program give proper output when executed on Compiler Explorer?

Comment: The Windows OS used by Compiler Explorer lacks the time zone database needed by `current_zone`. See https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/3500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is not bad.  You can also use `std::format` to customize the format of the time stamp.  And `std::format` returns a `std::string` directly:

```
const auto str = std::format("{}", time);
```

That gives the same format as what you have.

```
const auto str = std::format("{:%FT%TZ}", time);
```

This gives another popular (ISO) format.

[`std::format` lives in the header `<format>`.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)

[Here is the complete documentation for the chrono format flags.](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.format)

Comment: Yes I was looking for `std::format` too. I guess it's a more efficient solution. Tnx.